# Our email server is spammed with "Returned mail: see transcript for details"

Tags: email, email-server, spam

We are running a fairly popular online service and since this morning our email inbox is spammed with emails like this "Returned mail: see transcript for details" by "MAILER-DAEMON@localhost.localdomain":

```
The original message was received at Wed, 27 Jun 2018 19:33:06 +0800
from vm003 [127.0.0.1]

   ----- The following addresses had permanent fatal errors -----
<someguy@someprovider.com>
    (reason: 550 5.7.1 Client host [SOME-IP] blocked using Spamhaus. To request removal from this list see http://www.spamhaus.org/lookup.lasso (S3130). [CY1NAM02FT022.eop-nam02.prod.protection.outlook.com])

   ----- Transcript of session follows -----
... while talking to hotmail-com.olc.protection.outlook.com.:
>>> MAIL From:<info@example.com> SIZE=2800
<<< 550 5.7.1 Client host [SOME-IP] blocked using Spamhaus. To request removal from this list see http://www.spamhaus.org/lookup.lasso (S3130). [CY1NAM02FT022.eop-nam02.prod.protection.outlook.com]
554 5.0.0 Service unavailable



Reporting-MTA: dns; localhost.localdomain
Received-From-MTA: DNS; vm003
Arrival-Date: Wed, 27 Jun 2018 19:33:06 +0800

Final-Recipient: RFC822; someguy@someprovider.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.7.1
Diagnostic-Code: SMTP; 550 5.7.1 Client host [SOME-IP] blocked using Spamhaus. To request removal from this list see http://www.spamhaus.org/lookup.lasso (S3130). [CY1NAM02FT022.eop-nam02.prod.protection.outlook.com]
Last-Attempt-Date: Wed, 27 Jun 2018 19:33:07 +0800
```

If I understand correctly, the provider has blocked an email because the sender IP was on a blacklist. This IP [SOME-IP] is *not* the IP of our webserver, however the sender email info@example.com *is our* email address. That means an infected email server (that is not ours and not related to us) is sending out spam emails using our public email address. That is why the receiver mail server is informing us that this email was blocked for spam. Is my understanding of the case correct?

I think there is not much we can do at this point because we can not prevent anyone from using our public email adress as a sender, because basically it is just a String. But the amount of response emails we are receiving is overwhelming.

What action should we take? Is my understanding correct that our server seems not to be infected? How can we block those emails anyway, as they are spamming our inbox?